# Android Actionbar gravity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, gravity

I'm using v7 support library to implement Actionbar in my app. As you know app default icon and title is shown in action bar in left side and action views in the right. I want to change this. Is it possible? How?

Comment: AFAIK, AppCompat honors RTL/LTR language direction on newer devices. Otherwise, please do not change the behavior of the action bar, unless you can convince all of us here on StackOverflow that your approach will be a net benefit to the user, after subtracting out the mental cost of having to constantly deal with your app being "wrong" compared to every other app on their device.

Comment: Why dont you just do no action bar (full screen) and put in a non editable text box if you really want a title somewhere else?